Cannot cast from ByteArrayInputStream to String trying to load an image at jasper report
I'm trying to load an image at my report through an expression but im receiving the error:
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. Cannot cast from ByteArrayInputStream to String
                value = (java.lang.String)(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) ((java.lang.Object)parameter_logobrasao.getValue()))); //$JR_EXPR_ID=25$
                        <-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
2. Cannot cast from ByteArrayInputStream to String
                value = (java.lang.String)(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) ((java.lang.Object)parameter_logobrasao.getValue()))); //$JR_EXPR_ID=25$
                        <-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
3. Cannot cast from ByteArrayInputStream to String
                value = (java.lang.String)(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) ((java.lang.Object)parameter_logobrasao.getValue()))); //$JR_EXPR_ID=25$
                        <-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

Passing the logo by parameter with the type Object and casting to byte[] at expression:
<parameter name="logobrasao" class="java.lang.Object"/>
....

<image hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
   <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="557" height="150"/>
   <imageExpression><![CDATA[new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) $P{logobrasao})]]></imageExpression>
</image>

I'm taking the image with java:
...
logobrasao = getImageBytes();
                
parameters.put("logobrasao", logobrasao);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameter, beanDS);
...

Some way Jasper is trying to cast the expression to String automatically. How can I solve it?
Versions:

Jaspersoft Studio 6.21.3
jasperreports-3.7.6


Why do you think this would work?

This wouldn't  work, but why the Jasper is casting this to string without no explicit casting??

So, you just randomly try things and hope they work? To be clear, I don't use Jasper, but if I had to guess, you get the error because imageExpression by default expects a String (e.g. with a filename?). I've seen some examples where a class attribute was specified, but I've been unable to find actual documentation for it. I'd assume however that Jasper Studio allows you to configure things.

You probably need to specify the expected type for the image expression (mind the class attribute):
<image hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
   <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="557" height="150"/>
   <imageExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) $P{logobrasao})]]></imageExpression>
</image>

JasperReports 3.7.6 is 14 years old.  Setting the expected type for expressions is no longer needed, so you can consider upgrading to a more recent version.
